# to dispose (oneself) in a heavily negligent manner

Tags: verbs

While looking up the word "*flop*" in the American Heritage Dictionary
I stumbled on this definition:

"*flop*":
to dispose (oneself) in a heavily negligent manner: *to flop oneself in a chair.*

What does "*dispose oneself*" mean? Based on the definition below it seems to mean "*place oneself*" but I've never heard it expressed in such a way "*go somewhere*", "*sit somewhere*", completely different story.

To place or set in a particular order; arrange: "*Sally ... was beginning to loosen the upper sheet and dispose the pillows*" (Harriet Beecher Stowe).

Comment: dispose oneself here means to put your body in a certain position;

Comment: It's a hopelessly outdated / literary usage. Don't bother with it.

Comment: Not true: Collins Dictionary: American English Word forms: disˈposed or disˈposing
1.  to place in a certain order or arrangement
2.  to arrange (matters); settle or regulate (affairs)
3.  to make willing; incline
4.  to make susceptible or liable

Comment: I'd lump it in with [*he **disported** himself*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+disported+himself%2Che+disposed+himself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Just because these reflexive usages are still in dictionaries is no reason anyone who needs the resources of ELL should bother with them.

Comment: Bear in mind that they were explaining flop. In that sense, it is not hopelessly outdated.

Comment: @Lambie: When I google **define "to flop"**, I don't even need to leave the Google homepage to see *fall, move, or hang in a loose and ungainly way*. The OP here could have done that if all he wanted was to know what ***to flop*** means. I don't really see the point in querying *one specific* unfamiliar word in a definition, when there are so many other ways to see similar / synonymous terms. It just doesn't seem to address a "real-world" problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers All this criticism of OP's and their way of posing questions is spurious. He found it in the American Heritage Dictionary. Nothing wrong with that. And the definition works fine here. So what is your problem?

Comment: Well,  if you go to flop in the AHD: his definition is not even there. So, now what?https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=flop Maybe it's a dusty older version or something.

Comment: I don't intend to *criticize* the OP. I'm simply suggesting that there's no good reason to want to understand every *usage* (not even every *word*) that one finds in a dictionary. Sure, people are (pre)disposed to do or think certain things, and we dispose of garbage. But who today disposes themselves in a chair?

Comment: @FumbleFingers But sometimes these outdated usages are used in TV shows or movies, either humorously or for some other reason. Today I've heard "wish you good fair" and this means the same  as "wish you a good journey" but "fair" as a noun is an outdated usage. It's still good to know as much as possible because even though these usages are outdated if you don't know what they mean you are not able to enjoy even modern shows or movies all the same.

Comment: Harriet Beecher Stowe wrote *Uncle Tom's Cabin* 172 years ago. You've set yourself a task which even natural English speakers haven't mastered: the use of every word in every dialect throughout the ages. When we watch a show, we mostly know that a word or phrase doesn't have current usage, and infer what it probably means from the context.

Comment: @StaticBounce: I've been reading, writing, speaking, and hearing English for a good many decades, and I've *never* encountered "wish you good fair". Nor is there [a single instance of those 4 words occurring consecutively](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wish+you+good+fair%22) in all the millions of texts indexed by Google Books. So I don't know where you heard that, but I doubt it came from a competent native Anglophone. And I have no idea what you mean by *"fair" as a noun is an outdated usage* in that context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is from a show about Vampires who speak outdated version of English but the show is very well made and the person speaking the line is an English actor Matt Berry. I'm not suggesting here that people are using this word this way nowadays. I'm just saying that it's nice to know what it means as it can appear somewhere (such as a TV show about vampires) even today.

Comment: I suggest that the scriptwriters of your show either don't know or don't care that the usage you cite ***never had any currency in English*** (so long as people think it "sounds like" outdated English, historical accuracy is usually irrelevant in such contexts). I simply don't believe "fair" ever had a noun meaning applicable to your cited context.

Comment: ...OR it's feasible the line was supposed to be *I wish you good **fare*** (which may or may not have been the scriptwriter's intended spelling). There are still no written instances of those words in Google Books, but it's a credible "mock-archaic" mash-up of the verb in ***Fare** thee well* (which still survives as *"Farewell"*, same as *"God be with you"* survives as *"Goodbye"*). It's still not "accurate" though, and you learning it as ***fair*** is obviously a hindrance in terms of making sense of English.